# How to measure effective sample size for multivariate time series?

Tags: time-series, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working with images collected over time from a fixed camera. Since the scene doesn't change for long periods, my effective sample size is much lower than the actual number of images I've collected.

I would like to compute the effective sample size (ESS) for my data as [described here](https://andrewcharlesjones.github.io/journal/21-effective-sample-size.html). However, since each of the data points is an image and not a scalar, my time series is actually a vector time series: $$
S = \langle\vec{x}^{(1)}, \vec{x}^{(2)}, \ldots, \vec{x}^{(t)}, \ldots\rangle
$$
where $\vec{x}^{(t)}_{i,j}$ denotes the intensity of pixel $i,j$ at time $t$.

I am wondering how to compute the effective sample size in this multivariate setting.

One way would be to consider each pixel as a separate time series with its own effective sample size and to compute the average ESS over all pixels. Or I could compute the minimum ESS, though this would be extremely pessimistic since some background pixels rarely change value.

Is there a "better" or established way to compute effective sample size in a multivariate time series or image data?

Comment: "Effective sample size" has a meaning in the context of a statistical test.  What test(s) are you performing?

Comment: Great question. I am not performing statistical tests. I am trying to measure how much training data I "really have". Given the vagueness of what I'm trying to measure, I imagine the answer to my original question is that there is nothing standard I can apply here.